# How to use commitEditingStyle? (UITableViewCell-UITableView)

Tags: ios4, uitableview

I am looking at various possible ways to implement delete-edit-copy feature on the `UITableViewCell` elements of a `UITableView`.

The one I am trying now is based on the usage of the following methods:

```
        [tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];

        - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

I can see some advantages to use this approach, but there is one problem:

When I try it, I can make the red "**Delete**" button appear and work, but that is all.

Is there a mechanism by which I could also have "**edit**" and "**copy**" buttons ?
Or is it just not possible?

Thanks for any helpful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

I just understood that you are referring to the cell, not the TableView. For the cell, the following styles are provided:

- **UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete**: 
  The cell has the delete editing control; this control is a red circle enclosing a minus sign.
- **UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert**:
  The cell has the insert editing control; this control is a green circle enclosing a plus sign. You may use it for "copy".
- **UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone**: The cell has no editing control.

Further styles you have to implement on your own.

**Original Answer**

You can use the `editButtonItem` method of `UIViewController`. It returns a bar button item that toggles its title and associated state between "Edit" and "Done" (but not "Copy"). The default button action already invokes the `setEditing:animated:` method.

If you want another state, your have to create your own BarButtonItem.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds interesting. I want to look into it more in depth.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [DummyData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [_tableView reloadData];
    }       
}
```

Use this code. Hope it helps and please do the same with **UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert**